# How to know such classes like XmlWriter type and its sytnax?

Tags: xmlwriter

Might seems silly question and can learn from google but I am new to C# and trying to figure out possible future clarifications. So here is best places to ask.

For example:
Why do not we write;

```
XmlWriter writer = new XmlWriter("C:\\1.xml",settings);
```

instead writing;

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\1.xml",settings);
```

(No new keyword and .Create method.)

What is XmlWriter fully named as a class?

Also how do I know in BCL which class to instantiate how? Like how do I know its syntax if I do not know. What is the ieasy way? How can intelligence help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a factory method, it creates one of the derived classes like `XmlWellFormedWriter`,  `XmlAsyncCheckWriter`, etc. which depend on settings.

Comment: Is it special to BCL or users can create such classes?

Comment: You can create your own XmlWriter-derived classes, but then you'll have to use new because XmlWrite.Create won't know about them.